# What tools are available for translating (human) languages within HTML code?

Tags: html, internationalization, gruntjs, translation

Is there a tool or task runner that can take an HTML document in one language, parse out the content in general/specific HTML tags, run that content through Google translate, then put it back into the markup in the right place in new files? Basically, digest one source file and output multiple variations in different (non-computer) languages.

What I'm hoping for is:

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    привет мир!
</body>
</html>
```

Gets compiled to:

`en/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    Hello World!
</body>
</html>
```

`ru/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    привет мир!
</body>
</html>
```

`ch/index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    你好世界!
</body>
</html>
```

I obviously don't mind setting up some sort of Gruntfile or whatever that dictates the languages, destinations, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to piece together a solution using Ruby and Grunt. This could be refactored to be more robust, but it was a working solution, so I ran with it. Keep in mind, the translating script **overwrites** the source files. Only the Grunt starts making duplicates in new destinations.

Using the `easy_translate` Rub gem I wrote this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'easy_translate'

EasyTranslate.api_key = '' # Get from google

target_path = '' # path to translate

Dir.glob(target_path) do |item|
  next if item == '.' or item == '..' or item == '.svn'

  contents = ""
  update = ""

  File.open(item, "r") do |file|
    contents += file.read
    update += EasyTranslate.translate(contents, :from => :russian, :to => :en)
  end

  File.open(item, "w"){ }

  File.open(item, "w") do |file|
    file.write(update)
  end
end
```

Walking through this, each file in the `target_path` is checked if it’s a worthwhile item we make variables `contents` and `update` we’ll use to place in the old and new versions of the contents of the file, respectively. Then we open the file and fill up those variable. On line 20 we empty the file, then in the last block on lines 22-24 we write the update string into the file. I used `File.open(item, "w") {}` instead of `.truncate(0)` because I was getting random Unicode characters added to the contents of the file with the latter option. Again, overwriting the files in the translation process is not ideal. It'd be better to make a copy in a new destination, but I didn't do that.

The Ruby script returned a single line of minified HTML and broke Smarty templating, so I used used [grunt-prettify](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-prettify) and [grunt-text-replace](https://github.com/yoniholmes/grunt-text-replace) to prettify the HTML for ease of use and to make the Smarty stuff work again. The Gruntfile looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    'prettify': {
      options: {
        indent: 4,
        indent_char: ' ',
        wrap_line_length: 0,
        brace_style: 'expand',
        "unformatted": [
          "a",
          "code",
          "pre"
        ]
      },
      all: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'static_ugly',
        ext: '.html',
        src: ['*.html'],
        dest: 'static_pretty'
      }
    },

    'replace': {
      fix_smarty: {
        src: ['static_pretty/*.html'],
        overwrite: true,
        replacements: [{
          from: '{/ Strip',
          to: '{/strip'
        },{
          from: '{$ This-> setLayout ',
          to: '{$this->setLayout'
        },{
          from: '{$ this- > setPageTitle ',
          to: '{$this->setPageTitle'
        },{
          from: '$ this-> setPageTitle ',
          to: '$this->setPageTitle'
        },{
          from: '{$ smarty.block.footer ',
          to: '{$smarty.block.footer'
        }]
      }
    }

  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-prettify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-text-replace');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['prettify', 'replace']);
};
```

There was a lot more find/replace stuff that I left out since it's project-specific. This solution pretty much does what I wanted in the original question. I did some manual moving around of files in the name of getting it done, but I believe I'll be using a variation of this moving forward and consider it a work in progress.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [get-translation](https://github.com/tinganho/get-translation) or [grunt-google-translate](https://github.com/MartyIce/grunt-google-translate). Also Google Translate has simple [REST API](https://developers.google.com/translate/), you can write your own plugin from the scratch or use something like [grunt-restful](https://github.com/DaneStuckel/grunt-restful).